# Alias ssh to have a default -F flag

Tags: ssh, powershell, alias

I would like to "alias" `ssh` in my PowerShell profile to:

```
ssh -F $HOME\.ssh\config
```

I have a custom `$HOME` environment, but the Win32 OpenSSH implementation uses `%USERPROFILE%` which cannot be modified and the developers have no intent to switch to `$HOME` so I'm looking for an alternative way of forcing the `-F` flag.

I tried looking at `Set-Alias` but it does not seem to allow extra parameters, and I'm afraid I'll end-up in a recursive loop if I make a `ssh` function calling `ssh`...

Anyway to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

#### I tried looking at Set-Alias but it does not seem to allow extra parameters

It can be done.

The following example should be modifiable for your needs as you are always using the same arguments `-F $HOME\.ssh\config`:

> **Example 5: Create an alias for a command with parameters**
>
> This example shows how to assign an alias to a command with
> parameters.
>
> You can create an alias for a cmdlet, such as `Set-Location`. You
> cannot create an alias for a command with parameters and values, such
> `as Set-Location -Path C:\Windows\System32`.
>
> To create an alias for a command, create a function that includes the
> command, and then create an alias to the function. For more
> information, see [about_Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7).
>
> ```
> PS> Function CD32 {Set-Location -Path C:\Windows\System32}
> PS> Set-Alias -Name Go -Value CD32
> ```
>
> A function named CD32 is created. The function uses the `Set-Location`
> cmdlet with the `Path` parameter to `specify` the directory,
> `C:\Windows\System32`.
>
> The `Set-Alias` cmdlet creates an alias to the function in the current
> PowerShell session. The `Name` parameter specifies the alias's name,
> `Go`. The `Value` parameter specifies the function's name, `CD32`.
>
> To run the alias, type `Go` on the PowerShell command line. The `CD32`
> function runs and changes to the directory `C:\Windows\System32`.

Source [Set-Alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Well, the problem with that example is that `CD32` does not call `Go`. In my use case, I would have the function called `ssh` call `ssh` with default argument, so I guess it would enter an infinite recursion loop.

Comment: So call it myssh

Comment: Well, I want a `ssh` alias not a `myssh`...

Comment: @Holt unless I am mistaken you would only need to create the function - ```Function ssh {ssh.exe -F $HOME\.ssh\config}```. Testing this locally does not end up in an infinite loop as it calls the function rather than execute the ssh.exe which "ssh" typically would find via an environmental path. Caveats are that if you subsequently need to issue commands to ssh without ``` -F $HOME\.ssh\config```  you would have to use the full ssh.exe.

Comment: @CraftyB I ended up storing the full path to the ssh command before declaring the function and using it in it. I did not thought about using ssh.exe directly, thanks!

Comment: @Holt So you can accept my answer then :)